# Slow jQuery script for web form - optimization advice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very large form with a lot of fields spread throughout various divs.  Certain divs need to be hidden depending on the value of a certain dropdown field, #record_type_dd_c.

I am using a large (very basic) jQuery script to hide the necessary panels, but some users are reporting that the form is "slow" when editing and changing the dropdown.  It runs fine on my PC.

You will see in the code that there are basically two main sections.  The first is when a user edits an existing record.  In that case, the user is unable to edit the #record_type_dd_c dropdown as it is locked, so I just need the jQuery to see what the current value is in the dropdown and hide the appropriate panels.

The second case is when a user is creating a new record with the form.  In that instance, they are able to select the value of the dropdown and the form must hide the appropriate panels again.

The code works, but again, some users are reporting that it's rather slow.

My experience with jQuery/JS and web development is still in it's infant stages and I'm trying to figure out a way I can optimize my jQuery, as I'm guessing that it's just way too much code and certain user's computers aren't able to run the script fast enough?

Does anyone have any advice they could give to optimize this?  Any help is GREATLY appreciated.  Thank you!

```
  var recordType = $("#record_type_dd_c").val();                    

  switch (recordType) {

  case "":
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL33').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide();   
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();    
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();                                        
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();    
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();    
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();    
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide();   
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide();   
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide();   
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide();   
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide();   
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide();   
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide();   
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide();   
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide();   
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide();   
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide();
      $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide();
      break;

case "0124000000014qm":                         
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();                                      
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide(); 
    break;

case "01240000000990R":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL33').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide();
    break;

case "0124000000097fm":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide();         
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    break;

case "0124000000014DL":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide();     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL33').parent().hide();
    break;

case "01240000000141F":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide();     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();  
    break;

case "012300000000OQ2":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide();     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();
    break;

case "0124000000013eG":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide();     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();
    break;

case "0124000000015HJ":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();  
    break;
}


$("#record_type_dd_c").change(function () {
   $("[id*=LBL_EDITVIEW]").parent().show();
   var recordType = $("#record_type_dd_c").val();   

switch (recordType) {
case "0124000000014qm":                         
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();                                      
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide(); 
    break;

case "01240000000990R":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL33').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide();
    break;

case "0124000000097fm":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide();         
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    break;

case "0124000000014DL":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL33').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide();     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide();
    break;

case "01240000000141F":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide();     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();  
    break;

case "012300000000OQ2":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide();     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();
    break;

case "0124000000013eG":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL29').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL30').parent().hide();     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL31').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();
    break;

case "0124000000015HJ":                                     
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL24').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL37').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL10').parent().hide();
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL16').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL22').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL4').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL5').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL11').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL12').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL13').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL14').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL15').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL23').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL18').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL19').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL20').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL21').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL34').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL35').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL36').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL25').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL26').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL27').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL28').parent().hide(); 
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL8').parent().hide();  
    $('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL9').parent().hide();  
    break;
}
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your HTML structure, you could hide the parent of all the elements you want to hide, otherwise, I'd recommend adding a class to the groups of elements that you want to hide together i.e. group1, group2 then hide each group:

```
case '':
$('.group1').hide();
break;
```

Each dom query you do is expensive, so it's better to grab multiple elements with each query, than to do a query for each element.